# Problems with multiple conditions in while loop java

Tags: java, android, while-loop

I have problems with multiple conditions in a java `while` loop. I am trying to put conditions as not equal as null, but android studio says that `&&` cannot be applied to boolean. Any help is appreciated!

I am trying to do this:

```
String question = null, answer = null, answerOne = null,
        answerTwo = null, answerThree = null, answerFour = null;

while (((question = reader.readLine()) != null)
        && ((answer = reader.readLine()) != null)
        && (answerOne = reader.readLine()) !null)
        && ((answerTwo = reader.readLine()) != null)
        && (anwserThree = reader.readLine()) != null)
        && ((anwserFour = reader.readLine()) != null)) {

    //reading some lines from resource file
    Question q = new Question(question, answer, answerOne, answerTwo,
            answerThree, answerFour);
        mQuestions.add(q);
}
```

Comment: are you missing an = before your third null?

Comment: Learn to properly format your code first...

Answer (score 3):

You have malformed conditions.  This includes a missing opening parenthesis `(`, a `!` operator where a `!=` operator makes sense, a missing closing parenthesis `)`, and misspelling "answer" on 2 variables in the conditions.

Replace

```
(answerOne = reader.readLine()) !null)
```

with

```
((answerOne = reader.readLine()) != null)  // Two ( at beginning; !=
```

Replace

```
( anwserThree= reader.readLine()) != null)
```

with

```
((answerThree = reader.readLine()) != null) // Two ( at beginning; spelling
```

Replace

```
( (anwserFour= reader.readLine()) != null)
```

with

```
((answerFour= reader.readLine()) != null))  // Spelling; Two ) at end
```

Answer (score 2):

You have got a typo in a part of the while-condition:

`(answerOne = reader.readLine()) !null)`

should be:

`(answerOne = reader.readLine()) != null)`

Maybe that solves your issue?